# Vscode open the "Julia Plots" editor in a fixed location

Tags: visual-studio-code, plot, layout, julia

I'm using vscode for some julia coding. It was always fine. Lately, maybe after some auto updating, vscode starts to show a new editor following my mouse focus, which very mch bothers me because I want the "plot" editor in a fixed space. But every time in run the files, the plot editor pops up in the group with my file editors.

I searched online and checked the vscode documents. Relevant settings are default group/lock group. But none of it solves my problem.

Please lend a hand.

Comment: Are the `Julia: Focus Plot Navigator` and `Julia: Use Plot Pane` settings enabled?

Comment: they are. i tried switching them on and off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started having this same exact problem, not sure how to fix properly. If you want a quick fix downloading a previous version of vscode worked for me (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_62).

Comment: may i ask which particular version do you use right now? so it seems like a v1.63 problem?

Comment: I'm using 1.59 at the moment, but I suspect that 1.62 would work too, since the error happened so recently.

Comment: alright. i submitted and rollbacked too. really like the steady plot window now

Answer (score 2):

For me the following setting solved the issue with the latest vscode version:

Workbench > Editor: Reveal if Open -> Enabled

[Workbench > Editor: Reveal if Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qj5s.png)

Comment: Confirmed works for me, thx.  Note this setting can be found by clicking VSCode's "Manage" gear icon in bottom left >> click on Settings (or use keyboard shortcut to arrive at same place) >> type "Reveal if Open" in "Search settings" textbox.

Comment: thanks~ but i decided to stay at v1.59 so as to prevent any future unpredictable behavior:)